# Konjunktiv-Verwendung in "wann die Grenze erreicht wäre"

Tags: usage, subjunctive

Aus dem *Spiegel-Magazin*. Ein Leserbrief zum Thema "Selbstbestimmtes Sterben".

> Ich bin 75, der Kreis schließt sich langsam. Mein Mann und ich **würden** nicht leichtfertig mit unserem Leben umgehen, wissen aber, wann die Grenze erreicht **wäre**, und diese sollten nur wir bestimmen dürfen.

Warum wird der Konjunktiv hier in beiden Fällen verwendet? Sie scheinen mir als normale Sätze. Was sind die Hypothesen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die 75jährige ist zwar dem Tode näher als eine gesunde 25jährige, aber die Frage stellt sich noch nicht akut. Die Hypothese ist der Umgang mit dem Tode bzw. selbstbestimmten Sterben, wenn sich die Frage akut stellt. Dies vor allem vor dem Hintergrund, dass beide offenkundig Sterbehilfe für akzeptabel halten, wenngleich sie nicht leichtfertig damit umgehen wollen.

Indikativ wäre möglich, würde aber eine feste Absicht implizieren.